# spark.worker.cleanup does not work, logs are not deleted

Tags: apache-spark, worker

I want periodically cleanup the log files that stored in the ${SPARK_HOME}/logs for our spark cluster (1 master + 4 workers). 
The default log directory for spark logs should be ${SPARK_HOME}/logs, since I didn't configure the SPARK_LOG_DIR in spark-env, so all logs are being stored there.

In order to test it, I have added  the conf below (spark.worker.cleanup.enabled) in one of the worker node.

> export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true
>   -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=300 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=300"

And then executed stop-slave.sh to stop the worker node, and start the worker with start-slave.sh.
But those log files in ${SPARK_HOME}/logs are not being deleted after the configured interval time.

I would like to know am I doing the right step ? Or something more has to be done? I also put that spark.worker.cleanup conf in the master node's spark-env.sh. And I don't see any effect there also.

Comment: Did you try setting these properties in `spark-defaults.conf` used by the Worker process? I.e. on the Worker nodes, and under `$SPARK_HOME/conf/`

Comment: Note that the logs for the Worker process itself will not be purged, only the outputs from the Spark jobs (assuming you did not change the Log4J defaults i.e. dump to StdOut / StdErr and let the Worrker capture these dumps into log files). For the Worker logs, you may configure some "log rotation" via Log4J

Comment: Hi, I have multiple applications running on the same spark cluster , so each application have it owns sparkconf and log4j configuration. But right now I would like to setup the cleanup for cluster specific, not appliction centric .

Comment: I didn't change the spark-default.conf in the worker nodes, do I need to do it in order to make the cleanup work?

Comment: The properties set in the env variable should override what is set in the `defaults` -- providing that the env variable is _actually_ picked by the Worker process. It all depends on how you set the env, and how you start the Worker process. And whether the Spark documentation about the env variables is in line with the code base (I'm sometimes suspicious). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think I was a bit confused on which folder to cleanup. In the spark document, it mentioned the spark.worker.cleanup.enabled is only cleanup worker "APPLICATION" directory.

And our application directory is located at "spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7/work", and that directory did get cleaned up .

So after changing the spark-env.sh, and then stop-slave, and then start-slave again. Everything working good.

Comment: May I ask what did you change other than export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=300 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=300" , because I want to do that same thing but the `/work` is not getting cleaned up after setting those properties